# Where the hell is Dom for Uncalculated Risk on GTA 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have been trying to complete this mission forever.  I've watched the youtube videos of where you meet the dog at the reservoir/damn.  I know where he's supposed to show up.

I've completed all the parachute jumps AND all the Dom missions except this one.

I've even gotten a Gold achievement for the previous mission, which someone said had to be done.

I've also done the "fix" where you save to a new slot, go online and mess around, then switch back to Franklin.

STILL he, or the dog that leads to the mission is NOWHERE to be found.

I'm totally stuck, I'm beginning to give up.

Comment: I had to play with the internet disconnected when they had that issue over xmas and I had so many missions show up that I couldn't cross town without a mugger or security van showing up.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the following seems to be the only way players got out of this bug. It works for some people, but doesn't for others... (Also note the multiple loading, apparently that helped some people)

> - Make a new quick save in a new slot
> - Load it immediately (repeat up to 3 times)
> - Switch to online mode (online tab through the start menu)
> - Play online for a bit, 5-10 minutes. Do a mission or two.
> - Switch back to single player through the start menu

If this is not working for you, I'm afraid you will have to wait for a patch coming from R*

Comment: Well thanks for the comment.  I did try it like you said, no worky  :(  I even did it 3 times in a row and loaded as fast as my thumbs could go.  Did a mission online, took about 10 minutes.  Switched back through start.  I mean does it matter what time of day you go to the reservoir?    I dunno, seems like with so many complaints, they would have added a patch.

Answer (score -1):

Try playing the prologue and then try loading the previous save